# Generate csv file in awk command

Tags: awk

I am executing below awk command for splitting the files and generate the output in .CSV format. I tried many things to pass the correct syntax in the script to generate on csv file but no luck. Can some please let me know where to mention the correct syntax.

```
awk -v lines="30000" -v pre="awk_part_" '
        NR==1 { header=$0; next}
        (NR-1) % lines ==1 { fname=pre c++; print header > fname}
        {print > fname}' patient.tsv
```

How the above command works:

1. awk -v lines=”30000″ -v pre=”awk_part_” – First, I’ve declared two awk variables to define how many records are in each split file and the prefix of the filenames
2. NR==1 { header=$0; next} – When awk reads the first line, it stores the line in a header variable and stops further processing
3. (NR-1) % lines ==1 { fname=pre c++; print header > fname} – When the current line is the first record of a trunk, we need to update the filename (fname) by incrementing a counter (c). Also, since this would be a new file, we add the value of the header variable to the file as the first line
4. {print > fname}’ patient.tsv – Then, I've just redirected each record line to the current fname file

Comment: [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Obviously for [mcve] you'd set `lines=3` or similar, not 3000.

Comment: how to generate csv output file in the above awk command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> awk -v lines=”30000″ -v pre=”awk_part_” – First, I’ve declared two awk
> variables to define how many records are in each split file and the
> prefix of the filenames

According to [Options in GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html)

> ```
> -v var=val
> ```
>
> (...) Set the variable *var* to the value *val before* execution of the
> program begins. Such variable values are available inside the `BEGIN`
> rule(...).

You apparently attempt to use it outside `BEGIN`, please try using following code

```
awk 'BEGIN{lines=30000;pre="awk_part_"}
     NR==1 { header=$0; next}
     (NR-1) % lines ==1 { fname=pre c++; print header > fname}
     {print > fname}' patient.tsv
```

and check if it does produce what you wants.

Comment: Hi Daweo, after executing your script it's still not generating output file in the CSV format. The awk script which I am using works well in splitting the file with header, but not CSV format... I've tried with other script but that it taking time.. Is there a specific syntax that we can add in awk command to get in CSV format.

Comment: @user3776623 what files did it created? Did lines go to files which they were supposed to go?

Comment: lines went into files along with headers. Created file extension is FILE format.

Comment: @user3776623 if you want which ends with `.csv`, just add it to `fname` i.e. replace `pre c++` using `pre c++ ".csv"`

Comment: Finally, it worked!!! Thank you Daweo for your assistance. Finding the right way for a small & simple stuff takes time, but when it strives the cord it works like a Charm... I actually looked into so may forums but couldn't found these simple solution....

Comment: when splitting a CSV file using the above script it creates a file but removes any trailing zero values from the column value. Eg: 01234 converts to 1234 value.. Is there a way to alter the above AWK script?

Answer (score 0):

@Daweo, lines went into files along with headers. Created file extension in FILE type format. Refer screenshot[awk_part_o in FILE format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cC7Q.png)

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: You are aware that you can comment on your own question, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it and hence deleted the answered post. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: Yes..... and this post here? Is it supposed to be answering according to [answer]? It gives an impressin of being only a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/70181207/7733418 And you could instead comment there.